# Clipping large shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip, overlapping-features, performance

I am working on a large shapefile sourced from https://www.iucnredlist.org/resources/spatial-data-download. I cannot clip Fish and Plants (global file) in Freshwater groups species to a smaller extent (country level).

I tried clipping in QGIS but could not get the output. QGIS return an error: intersection failed. However, the clip works perfectly fine for all other datasets. I have successfully clipped other (smaller in size) shapefiles. I found a link where it suggested using 'Clip by extent' in GDAL, but it gave an empty shapefile having no data.

How can it be solved?

[image]

For the extent, let's say, I want to clip it to India's extent.
In QGIS, the error is:

[image]

Comment: I checked the shared URL and I suspect it's the first one on the List? Add a few screenshots of the extent you are working with and the returned error message when trying to clip in QGIS, as ArcMap crashes.

Comment: If you also want to ask about ArcMap then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: @YogeshChavan I want to clip it to India's extent. In qgis, I am getting error: intersection failed. I have started process and attach screenshot when it finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In QGIS try:

1. Fix geometries, save the output as geopackage.
2. Create spatial index.
3. Clip

If it still doesnt work:

4. Multipart to Singlepart the spatial index output.
5. Create spatial index
6. Clip

Comment: can you please elaborate your steps? or please provide some links for these steps. I am quite new to GIS analysis, not able to follow these.

Comment: @rgt Also save shapefile as geopackage before processing.

Comment: Fix Geometries worked. First I had to use fixed geometries, then the resulting file used for clipping produced desired result.